# Visual layout of structs on stack (AT&T x86, C)

Tags: c, struct, x86, stack, offset

I'm currently trying to understand how the function *func* accesses variables in a structure. I have to fill in the ? based on given assembly code.

```
typdef struct point{
    float *p;
    struct{
    float x;
    float y;
    } s;
    struct point *next;
} point;

void func(point *sp1, point *sp2){
    sp2->p = ?;
    sp2->s.x = ?;
    sp2->s.y = ?;
    sp1->next = ?;
    sp2->next = ?;
}

int main(){
    point *init, *final;
    // assume init has been initialized to some value
    func(init, final);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

I'm unsure how to visualize this for myself so that I can answer the question. Starting from when we call func,I get this far in drawing the stack:

```
STACK BASE
   .           .
   .           .
   .           .
  sp2        0xc(%ebp)
  sp1        0x8(%ebp)
ret addr     0x4(%ebp)
--ebp--
   .
   .
   .
TOP OF STACK
```

My confusion arises in:

1. How to offset from ebp correctly (the space between addresses)
2. How to deal with sp2
3. If I've set up the sp1 variables correctly.
4. How the assembly code interacts with the variables inside each struct.

Comment: Not related to your question but `point *init, *final;` doesn't allocate space for these structures. it only allocates space for the pointers themselves (and they are uninitialized). `funct` will probably crash when you attempt to alter data at an uninitialised pointer. You should probably use `point init, final;` to allocate space (on the stack in the case) and then pass the addresses with `func(&init, &final);`

Comment: I see, interesting as this was a problem given to me to solve, not my own code.

Comment: The fields of `sp1` and `sp2` won't be passed on the stack as arguments. Only the pointers `sp1` and `sp2` themselves.

Comment: `0x8(%ebp)` is the `sp1` parameter. `0xc(%ebp)` is the `sp2` parameter.

Comment: For a structure object the compiler will allocate a vector of memory and will generate code to read/write objects from that space, each object starting from different offsets. You can visualize the offset either via offsetof(field) or via (&(char*)s.obj - &(char*)s)

There are atomic instructions in x86 to implement field-access of structures in a single operation (in case of nested structures it computes the offset as well). -- I moved the answer as a comment, as it is just a general answer.

Comment: As far as I can understand so far:

1. We move the pointer to sp1 into eax

2. Load address of sp1 + 0x4 (why?) into edx
3. Move pointer sp2 into eax
4. Move address of sp1+0x4 into address pointed at by eax (what does this do?)

I'd like to understand this before moving forward as I think understanding this could help with the rest.

Comment: `sp1+4` is the address of `sp1->s`, which is also the address of `sp1->s.x`. So this sets `sp2->p = &sp1->s.x`.